# How does & work when the operands are of different size in C

Tags: c

I am just wondering could someone explain the following code and what is being output?

I am kind of confused about how it works? does it involve integer promotion or type conversion when & is being used here?  Could someone explain a bit? I tried to do some bitwise & between two numbers, but results don't come out to be expected.

```
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    int x1 = 11 & 0xa; // 0x132d
    int x2 = 11 & 0xb; // 0x132d
    int x3 = 11 & 0xc;   //  is this 0011 & 1100 ?
    int x4 = 11 & 0xd; //   is this 0011 & 1101?
    int x5 = 11 & 0xe; //  is this 0011 & 1110?
    int x6 = 11 & 0xf; // is this 0011 & 1111?
    
    printf("%0d \n", x1);
    printf("%0d \n", x2);
    printf("%0d \n", x3);
    printf("%0d \n", x4);
    printf("%0d \n", x5);
    printf("%0d \n", x6);

    return 0;
}
```

and this is the output:

```
Hello World
0 
1 
4 
5 
4 
5
```

Comment: Explained by https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Usual_arithmetic_conversions

Comment: What hardware was this run on?

Comment: There are no integer promotions; both the operands of each `&` operation are of type `int`, and the result is an `int` too, even before the assignment. It is not clear what your first two annotations refer to — 0x132D does not figure in the calculations at all.   Decimal 11 has the binary representation 1011; 0xA has the representation 1010; the result of 11 & 0xA should be 10.  11 is the same as 0xB so the result there should be 11.  How are you getting other values?

Comment: Unless you're striving for obfuscation, why no just use `0x0b & ...` for all those bitwise-and left sides, because that's exactly what it is. It also explains [the real output](https://godbolt.org/z/nGacb5srd). So, as @जलजनक asked, what did you run this on, and is this the *exact* code you used?

Comment: Is the output you show what your computer produces or what you expect?  If it is what your computer produces, your compiler is broken — irretrievably broken.  If it is what you expect, you should explain why you expect that.

Answer (score 1):

All about your target type either decimal or binary as 0xB & 0xC. (1011 & 1100 in binary).

According to your code --> output is:

```
Hello World
10 
11 
8 
9 
10 
11
```

Answer (score 0):

> How does & work when the operands are of different size

- When an operands is narrow, it is promoted to an `int` or `unsigned`, whichever type encompassed the range of the narrow object.  (Does not apply here are both operands are already `int`s.
- Then the lower ranked operand is converted to the higher one.
- Then `&` is applied - both operands now being the same time.  The result is of this common type.

---

> `int x3 = 11 & 0xc;   //  is this 0011 & 1100 ?`

No.  It is like `0xB & 0xC`.  (1011 & 1100 in binary)

Comment: Hi, could you explain what you mean by your last bullet point?  what do you mean by "both operands not being the same time"?

Comment: @john_w Typo fixed: "both operands _now_ being the same time"

Answer (score 0):

In computer memory,it just like that.
`32-bit operating system`

```
11 & 0xa; 00001011 & 1010
11 & 0xb; 00001011 & 1011
11 & 0xc; 00001011 & 1100 
11 & 0xd; 00001011 & 1101
11 & 0xe; 00001011 & 1110
11 & 0xf; 00001011 & 1111
```

When you use operation symbol `&`

```
11 & 0xa;
   `0`0000000000000000000000000001011 & 000000000000000000000000`0`0001010
-> `0`0000000000000000000000000001010 
-> output 10
```

when you change 11 to -11

```
-11 & 0xa;
   `1`0000000000000000000000000001011
-> `1`1111111111111111111111111110100
-> `1`1111111111111111111111111110101 & 000000000000000000000000`0`0001010
-> `0`000000000000000000000000000000000
-> output 0
```